# .htaccess change to another domain, depending language

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Ive been looking around Google for the answer but i cant seem to find it. Im trying to make a redirect based on language of the website.

I have 2 domainnames that both point to the same IP.

What I would like to have

```
mywebsite.be/en -> mywebsite.co.uk/en
mywebsite.co.uk/nl -> mywebsite.be/nl
mywebsite.be/nl -> mywebsite.be/nl
```

Can somebody help me please,

Thanks!

Vincent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file of each site:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mywebsite\.be$
RewriteRule ^nl(/.*)?$ http://mywebsite.be/nl/$1 [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mywebsite\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^en(/.*)?$ http://mywebsite.co.uk/en/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but when I do this it keeps redirecting if I go to mywebsite.co.uk/nl